# AWS S3 error when there are Chinese characters in the userMetaData of `PutObjectRequest`

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

If I have Chinese characters in value of `userMetaData` of `PutObjectRequest`:

[image]

I will get the 400 bad request:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1722)
```

And the following one with different Chinese characters:

[image]

result in 403 error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 1C11613460118BAE; S3 Extended Request ID: 6iq+ertFiYjXgJJhKWTFr6qhSenkwqk3OOp05xYaIlp6jrlsWJK8PQhoGSiWYAu2CFbLK5X5zEw=)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1722)
```

Note if the there is no Chinese characters in the userMetaData then everything works perfect.

My AWS SDK version is `1.11.177`

Comment: What is the question? Or would you create a bug report to Amazon?

Comment: @Konrad Just want to check if anyone has encountered the issue or has any solution/workaround. In terms bug report, where should I submit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a reportable bug... it is a documented limitation in the REST interface of S3.

> User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata keys in lowercase. **Each key-value pair must conform to US-ASCII when using REST** and UTF-8 when using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST. (Emphasis added.)
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

SOAP is deprecated (not to mention terrible), and even though POST uploads will allow you to store UTF-8 characters in metadata, don't do it, because you may be unable to work with the object or read back the metadata.

In contrast with object metadata, object *tagging*   **does** support UTF-8.

> A tag key can be up to 128 Unicode characters in length and tag values can be up to 256 Unicode characters in length.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html